# Stack trace says create.js.erb is rendering but alert('test') isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

My stack trace says `Rendered comments/create.js.erb (4.0ms)`, but `alert('test');` isn't being executed (nor is the code beneath it). Why is this?

**Stack Trace**

```
Started POST "/articles/6/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-25 14:45:07 -0400
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"author"=>"six", "body"=>"six"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "article_id"=>"6"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.8ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("article_id", "author", "body", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["article_id", 6], ["author", "six"], ["body", "six"], ["created_at", Sun, 25 May 2014 18:45:07 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sun, 25 May 2014 18:45:07 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.7ms)  commit transaction
  Article Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "6"]]
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."article_id" = 6
  Rendered comments/_list_comments.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered comments/create.js.erb (4.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 8.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for [@article, @comment], remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :author, required: false %>
    <%= f.input :body, required: false %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
        @comment.article_id = params[:article_id]
        if @comment.save
            respond_to do |f|
                f.html { redirect_to article_path(@comment.article_id), notice: 'Comment created!' }
                f.js {
                    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
                    @comment = @comment
                    @comments = Comment.where(article_id: params[:article_id])
                }
            end
        else
            respond_to do |f|
                f.html { redirect_to article_path(@comment.article_id), warning: 'Unable to create comment.' }
                f.js {
                    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
                    @comment = @comment
                    @comments = Comment.where(article_id: params[:article_id])
                }
            end
        end
    end

    private

        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :body)
        end
end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
alert('test');
$("#comments_listing").html(<%= j render 'comments/list_comments' %>);
```

**_list_comments.html.erb**

```
<div id="comments_listing">

<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <hr />
    <p><small><%= comment.author %></small></p>
    <p><%= comment.body %></p>
<% end %>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at what is being rendered on your browser.

But I think that the error is that you should call the html method like this:

```
$("#comments_listing").html("<%= j render('comments/list_comments') %>");
```

If you don't add the quotes the script will fail.